# How to use command "python3" to execute "/usr/local/bin/python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, redhat

I've set up python3.6 on new server and defualt python version of it is 2.7.
and I want to use command "python3" instead of "/usr/local/bin/python3.6"

python2.7 should be stayed as the default version, I just want to utilize "python3" command. 
Am I supposed to do use Symbolic link or alias? 
Is it ok if I'll create virtual envs?

I apologize for my dump question, and I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: On some linux distributions, e.g. Ubuntu, it is already set up to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `/usr/local/bin/` is in your PATH (echo $PATH).
If not, add it (`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/`) in your ~/.bashrc.
Restart the shell or `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks. I've added the path at the bash file. It works well~!

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias for this.

i.e. `alias python3=/usr/local/bin/python3.6` and put it to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Run `source ~/.bashrc` to get the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access in simpler way you can create the symbolic link or alias and use. In this case you will have both versions accessed via "python" and "python3" respectively.

In case of virtual envs, you need to create virtual env for "python3" and to use it you should activate it. When you activate the virtual env it will make the "python3" as default (i.e you will access it as "python" and not as "python3". There will be a symbolic link created for that). You can refer to the [link](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) for using virtual envs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using RHEL 7 as that has the default of Python 2.7. I recommend using the Red Hat provided Software Collections for Python 3.6 as per the following [installation instructions](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world/). Software Collections on RHEL 7 enable you to properly have 2 versions of Python (or other things) without breaking anything. Here is the [introduction guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html-single/packaging_guide/index#chap-Introducing_Software_Collections) to software collections. Here are the [release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html-single/3.3_release_notes/index#sect-RHSCL-About).